# PHP-Netbeans: How to change formatting for multi-conditional if statements

Tags: netbeans, code-formatting, netbeans-7.3

I have the following Code:

```
if(
    condition1
    && condition2
    && condition3
) {
    // do something
}
```

And after having netbeans reformat it i get

```
if(
    condition1 && condition2 && condition3
) {
    // do something
}
```

which is not what I want.

I already tried changing Editor>Formatting>PHP>Wrapping>If Statement - but I could not even figure out what this option does, but at least it seems not to solve my issue.

How can I make netbeans format multiconditonal ifs as I like them (or just leave them as they are)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans has changed the syntax slightly. You'll need to do a line break at the end of the AND operator instead of before and it will retain the breaks after a format.

```
if(
    condition1 &&
    condition2 &&
    condition3
) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.

I would have liked them to be in front, since these lines can get just long, so it would be better to directly see if it is AND or OR (without potential need of scrolling on smaller screens), but it is better then having everything in one line anyway. Thx

Comment: When the second or third conditions is `!condition1`, not work. The result is: `if(condition1 or ! condition2) ...`

Comment: Any options to keep `&&` in front?