# NeatBeans for PHP and exceptions to formatting rules

Tags: php, netbeans

Is there a way to ignore/make an exception for the specific formatting rule?
Example I'm currently having problem with:

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 ...)
```

Sometimes I want all conditions to be on the same line, sometimes I want, each condition on the new line, depending on the length of condition, but currently, when I apply formatting rules, all of the conditions automatically get brought back to the same line. I don't want it to be predefined, I want to be able to choose type of formatting on case by case basis. I've seen this question: [PHP-Netbeans: How to change formatting for multi-conditional if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921766/php-netbeans-how-to-change-formatting-for-multi-conditional-if-statements), and I can use the answer provided there, as a kind of hack, but I'm not really happy with that solution, and the bigger question remains, can specific rule be ignored? Overall I'm loving NetBeans (just started using it), but this would be a huge minus in my eyes, if we aren't given flexibility to customize which formatting rules to use and which to ignore. I don't even know which rule governs formatting of if statement conditions, by the way, so knowing that would be helpful too