# Netbeans "if" formatting

Tags: if-statement, netbeans-8

I'm making custom "if" formatting. For example:

```
if (
   some_expression
   && some_expression
   && some_expression
   && some_expression
)
```

But when I use format my custom formatting become  broken

```
if ( some_expression && some_expression && some_expression && some_expression )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have find this answer

[PHP-Netbeans: How to change formatting for multi-conditional if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921766/php-netbeans-how-to-change-formatting-for-multi-conditional-if-statements)

It is not complete but more useful

Answer (score 0):

You could define in

```
Menu Tools -> Options -> Editor -> tab Formating
```

Choose Language "Java"

There you have several categories.

I think that in Category "Wrapping" you could find something that will help.
At the end of the list you have "Binary Operators, Ternary operators.
Try to play around and choose what suites you best.

Comment: Wrapping haven't impact for this case